# AS3: Print Job without Print Dialog Box/Print Setup Dialog

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printing, dialog

Is there a way to print a job without the print dialog box.It will look for the default printer then it will also print all pages.After I click the print button, inside of the movieclip will be print all. Then how can I do it? I don't need AS3 swf not Air if possible..

Here's the code I'm using..

```
print_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,printContent);

function printContent(evt:MouseEvent) {
    var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

    if (printJob.start()) {

        if (content_mc.width>printJob.pageWidth) {
            content_mc.width=printJob.pageWidth;
            content_mc.scaleY=content_mc.scaleX;
        }

        printJob.addPage(content_mc);

        printJob.send();
    }
}
```

NOTE:

I already used the start2() but this code is for AIR.

Answer (score 1):

It appears there's an answer out there just did some googling:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/854070

```
var pj:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
var started:Boolean = pj.start2(null, false);
if(started)
{
     pj.addPage(this);
     pj.send();
};
pj = null;
```

Comment: @shaunhusain..Thanks, I was trying to disabled the print setup..and the one you paste didn't work...My last problem for now is remove the print setup... and I'd like to use swf only not air